# Convention about delta x in Waves Interference

Tags: waves

[image]

They seem to adopt a convention that delta x must always be positive.

Otherwise, there is no way to know what the phase difference of the sources actually means.

Does a 90° difference mean that source two has a 90° difference compared to source one, or does it have a -90° difference? So, they seem to adopt that convention that delta x must always be positive, which is the only way we could plug and chug an equation and be certain of the answer.

Am I right?